# code to show or hie content after clicking button

Tags: html, jquery

I have a read more button which was working before where it slides up or down to view more or less text. However, the moment I surrounded the button with a .center div tags to help with positioning, the button does not display or hide the content on click. I'm guessing it's with the line of code where it tries to find the parent. How do I get around this?

HTML and Jquery:

```
<p>Text</p>

<div class="full-text">

<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>

<div class="center">
<button class="readmore">Read More</button>
</div>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.full-text').hide();
    
        jQuery('.readmore').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            jQuery(this).parent().find('.full-text').slideToggle('slow');
            jQuery(this).text($(this).text() == 'Less' ? 'Read More' : 'Less');
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve], that shows the exact HTML structure you have.

Comment: You edited your question, but `<div class="center">` being a child of `<div class="full-text">` does not make sense, because your code would still not work even if `button` would not be wraped in `<div class="center">`

Comment: Ah that's how it works, so it's parent and parent again. Cool, thanks @t.niese

Comment: I know how it should work. But I'm pretty sure there is a `</div>` missing after the last `<p>Text</p>`, otherwise the `Read More` button would not be visible. Anyhow you most of the time don't want to use `parent()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your code to fail when the button is wrapped into a `div` is the `parent()` in `jQuery(this).parent().find('.full-text')` because `parent` will now refer to the element you wraped around the button.

Using `parent()` is generally a bad idea, you most of the time want to use `closest()`.

So a better setup would be to create a container in which you place your text full text and button and give that container class like `article`.

You will then select that container with `.closest('.article')`. Using that container you can search for your `.full-text` element.

If you do so, it does not really matter how deep your button or `.full-text` is nested in your `article` element which makes your code way easier to maintain.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.full-text').hide();

  jQuery('.readmore').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery(this).closest('.article').find('.full-text').slideToggle('slow');
    jQuery(this).text($(this).text() == 'Less' ? 'Read More' : 'Less');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="article">
  <p>Text</p>

  <div class="full-text">

    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>

  <div class="center">
    <button class="readmore">Read More</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check this.. You basically missed a " at <div class="full-text>

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.full-text').hide();
    
        jQuery('.readmore').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            jQuery(this).parent().parent().find('.full-text').slideToggle('slow');
            jQuery(this).text($(this).text() == 'Less' ? 'Read More' : 'Less');
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px!important; margin-bottom: 15px; line-height: 20px!important;">At Balance Coffee, we roast sustainable, speciality grade coffee that you'll want to sip on every single day. Bursting with flavours such as bright citrus, fudgey chocolate and sweet stone fruits, our coffees are exactly what you need to level up your morning brew.</p>

<div class="full-text">

<p style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px!important; margin-bottom: 15px; line-height: 20px!important;">We pride ourselves on being one of the best coffee beans suppliers in the UK, so you can enjoy our delicious single origin coffees or bold blends. Don’t want the fuss? Order once, via our subscription and you’ll never have to buy coffee beans online in the UK again!</p>
<p style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px!important; margin-bottom: 15px; line-height: 20px!important;">If you really want to kick your coffee up a notch, you should also check out our coffee accessories and equipment. Between our filter coffee kits, <a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/sage-coffee-machine-faqs/">Sage espresso machines</a> and beautiful Pesado accessories, we’ve got everything a budding home barista could need. Pair our coffee accessories with our world-class speciality coffees, and you’ve got yourself a set-up that any barista would kill for.</p>
<p style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px!important; margin-bottom: 15px; line-height: 20px!important;">With Balance, you can drink the best coffee in London from the comfort of your home. It just doesn’t get better than that!</p>
</div>
<div class="center">
<button class="vc_btn3-container vc_btn3-center vc_general vc_btn3 vc_btn3-size-md vc_btn3-shape-square vc_btn3-style-modern vc_btn3-color-black readmore">Read More</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `prev()` to get the previous sibling after getting the parent.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.full-text').hide();

  jQuery('.readmore').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery(this).parent().prev('.full-text').slideToggle('slow');
    jQuery(this).text($(this).text() == 'Less' ? 'Read More' : 'Less');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Text</p>

<div class="full-text">

  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
</div>
<div class="center">
  <button class="readmore">Read More</button>
</div>
```